# How to change shape color in excel using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, shapes

I need to automatically import a picture into excel and add a red circle. I am just starting to get the create a shape part but I cannot seem to figure out how to modify it. I have:

```
$WS = $workbook.worksheets.add()
$WS.select()
$ws.Activate()

$ws.Shapes.AddShape(9, 0, 0, 50, 50)
$circle = $ws.Shapes.AddShape(18, 50, 50, 50, 50)
#$Circle = $ws.Shapes[2]



write-host "fill: " $circle.fill
```

This adds an oval and a donut, but just outputs "system comobject" and I can't seem to access any of the methods that should be there (like fill/fillform.forecolor). What is the correct way to play with and modify the shape?

Comment: I wonder if you need to select and activate the sheet. Try deleting both. If that fails, I'd try activate, rather than select. Unfortunately I can't test myself, but from a VBA point of view, this should hold true. Not so sure if PowerShell plays by the same rules though.

Comment: The above comment is just an observation, not intended to be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test at the moment but try `$circle.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255,0,0)`. Change the RGB values to your preference.